# Как принудительно активировать стиль для элемента через JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation

Не получается активировать стиль из JS для элемента. Если смотреть в браузере через код элемента, то стиль нормально определяется, но он не активирован т.е. не стоит галочка в стилях  [image: как то так]

Что за беда? !important не помогает

JS - код

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
  }

  function ChangeIt() {
    var first = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/fpsrZ5xDDrakHMhAfb/giphy.gif";
    var second = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/ewibTu8n0jCzrbztqy/giphy.gif";
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('twitch-follow')[1];
    if (elem.getElementsByClassName("tag")[0].innerText == "FOLLOW") {
      var num = getRandomIntInclusive(1, 2);
      if (num == 1)
        elem.style.background = "url(" + '"' + first + '"' + ") no-repeat !important";
      else
        elem.style.background = "url(" + '"' + second + '"' + ") no-repeat !important";
    }
    console.log("complete");
  }
  ChangeIt();
}
```

Comment: Нет, это не тот стиль. У вас вообще видимо не выполняется ни первое не второе условие

Comment: Кстати, надо `if (num == 1) `, а не `if (num = 1) `

Comment: условие выполняется, но толку 0...

Comment: Как вы определили, что условие выполняется?

Comment: if (num == 1) {
      elem.style.background = "url("+'"'+first+'"'+") no-repeat !important";
      [подписал сюда] console.log("TRUE");
}
   else{
      elem.style.background = "url("+'"'+second+'"'+") no-repeat !important";
      [подписал сюда] console.log("FALSE");}

вообще изменение стиля должно произойти в любом случае... даже если условие не выполнится т.е. будет FALSE

Comment: Почему вы решили, что код до это условия вообще доходит?

Comment: ну наверное, я бы не получал сообщение в консоли "TRUE" или "FALSE"

Answer (score 2):

Можно сколько угодно к `background` добавлять `!important` и даже прописывать стили *inline*, но...

Пока не измените `opacity`, ничего не выйдет.

```css
/* Установили фон... */
.twitch-follow .background {
  background: url(https://media4.giphy.com/media/ewibTu8n0jCzrbztqy/giphy.gif) no-repeat !important;
}
/* ... а прозрачность не выключили! */
div.background {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<li class="twitch-follow">
  <div class="background">Zzz...</div>
</li>
```

Вы скромно умалчиваете про следующее css-правило:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что там осталось за пределами скриншота, нам неведомо, но причина там.

Comment: спасибо, я не заметил просто т.к. css не мой как и сайт

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `background-image` вместо `background`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
  }
 
  function ChangeIt() {
    var first = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/fpsrZ5xDDrakHMhAfb/giphy.gif";
    var second = "https://media4.giphy.com/media/ewibTu8n0jCzrbztqy/giphy.gif";
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('twitch-follow');
    if (elem[0].getElementsByClassName("tag")[0].innerText == "FOLLOW"){
       var num = getRandomIntInclusive(1,2);
       elem[0].style.backgroundImage =`url("${(num == 1 ? first: second)}")` 
    }
      console.log("complete");
  }
  ChangeIt();
}
```

```css
.twitch-follow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.tag{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:black">
  <div class="twitch-follow ">
    <span class="tag">
      FOLLOW
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="twitch-follow ">
    <span class="tag">
      FOLLOW
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

либо можно настроить классы и использовать их

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
  }
  function ChangeIt() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('twitch-follow');
    if (elem[0].getElementsByClassName("tag")[0].innerText == "FOLLOW"){
       var num = getRandomIntInclusive(1,2);
       elem[0].classList.add(num == 1 ? 'first': 'second' ) 
    }
      console.log("complete");
  }
  ChangeIt();
}
```

```css
.twitch-follow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.first{
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://media4.giphy.com/media/fpsrZ5xDDrakHMhAfb/giphy.gif") no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.second{
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://media4.giphy.com/media/ewibTu8n0jCzrbztqy/giphy.gif") no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:black">
  <div class="twitch-follow ">
    <span class="tag">
      FOLLOW
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="twitch-follow ">
    <span class="tag">
      FOLLOW
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```